# Code in post preview doesn't match live view

Tags: bug

I've seen this behavior for quite some time but I'm finally posting about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722516/2191572

Preview:

[image]

Live:

[image]

Comment: The highlighter [auto-guessed the code block to be Markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUfWO.png), and highlighted in light of that, it happens from time to time in weird places. Specifying a language for every code block is a good way to guard against this. As for why the preview doesn't match the actual output... the highlighter script could've timed out? The server-side and client-side renderers also have some occasional differences, it could be that too.